# Bootstrap - Having a text div resize dynamically across image size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Bootstrap and have a container with one row and a column with the following classes:

```
col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12
```

Inside the column, I have a div with an image and another div called `img-text` containing text. I have formatted `img-text` to display over the image but would like the div to stretch across the image dynamically when I resize the page. Please see the image for more details.

[image]

Here's what I have so far.

```css
.img_text {
  height: 60px;
  width: 90.5%;
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Georgia', Times, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12' id='col1'>
  <img src='img/ph1.jpg' class='img-responsive' />
  <div class='img_text'>Apples</div>
</div>
```

Comment: .img_text try adding width 100%

Answer (score 0):

Adjust `.img_text{width: 100%;}`

p.s. it might cause a bug at a bigger screen size. In that case, you'll need to use [media rules](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

```css
.img_text {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Georgia', Times, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12' id='col1'>
  <img src='img/ph1.jpg' class='img-responsive' />
  <div class='img_text'>Apples</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try iy

```
.img_text {
  height: 60px;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  float:left;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Georgia', Times, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

and

```
#col1{
overflow:hidden;
}
```